# React Reduct - Select Onchange get method request

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, get

I have the following situation,  i provide the a [codesandbox demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/crazy-bush-ob2ps) to demonstrate my existing problem.

A bit of explanation about and how to reproduce the case

I am here in the component `League.js`, any league in the list has a link

```
<a href={`#${item.league_id}`} onClick={(e) => onClick(e, item.league_id)}>

  const onClick = (evt, id) => {
    evt.preventDefault();
    getDetail(id)
  };
```

The onclick function populates in the `Details.js` component the `select options` with the names of the teams. You can see below.

```
  if (teamsDetail.length) {
    details = (
      <select value={selectedOption} onChange={selectTeamStat}>
        {teamsDetail && teamsDetail.length > 0
          ? teamsDetail.map(item => (
              <option key={`${item.team_id}`} value={item.team_id}>
                {item.name}
              </option>
            ))
          : null}
      </select>
    );
  }
```

This is now the problem i have in  `Detail.js` component, when i select the team name in my select i want send a get request `getStats` where i have to set two parameters ( `team_id and league_id` )

Here the relevant code

```
const [selectedOption, setSelectedOption] = useState("");

  const selectTeamStat = evt => {
    const { value } = evt.target;
    setSelectedOption(value);
    getStats(357, value);
  };
```

At the moment i can only pass the `team_id` which is the select value `selectedOption`

How can i also pass the `league_id` parameter?

I have hardcoded now putting `357` but i need to use the parameter `league_id`. How can i pass it from `League.js` Component?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured it out how to pass the `leagueId` state

These the steps i have done

In the `reducers/index.js` i have created an initial state

```
RECEIVE_LEAGUE
  league:[],

case RECEIVE_LEAGUE:
  return {...state, leagueId: action.json};
```

In the `actions/index.js`

```
export const receivedLeague = json => ({
  type: RECEIVE_LEAGUE,
  json: json
});
```

I have added a dispatch in the `getTeamsDetailById(id)`

```
dispatch(receivedLeague(id));
```

In the `Details.js` component

I have added the state `leagueId` on top

and edited my selectTeamStat function

```
  const [selectedOption, setSelectedOption] = useState('');

  const selectTeamStat = (evt) => {
     const { value } = evt.target;
     setSelectedOption(value)
     getStats(leagueId, value);
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

On the top of my head, here's two solutions you may want to try:

Set each of you select's options as a tuple:

```
value={[item.league_id, item.team_id]}
```

or set each of you select's options' `team_id` and `league_id` as data-attributes

Comment: The problem is that i do not have the team_id value and i need to know how to pass it from 1 component to the other

Comment: Ok so correct me if I'm wrong. You have a link (should be a button btw) that when clicked populates `teamDetails` from a `league_id`, right?
Why not simply store the `league_id` next to/in the `teamDetails` so you can have them both?

Could you please provide a working sandbox? Yours only shows infinite loaders.

Comment: Correct, the sandbox is not working probably because of the cors from your end, i use CORS Unblock google extension. I need to understand how to store the league_id in teamdetails or in the component in some way